# Downside of having long keep alive time for MQTT less often PINGREQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt

I am planning to use GCP IoT Core for my IoT project. In GCP each PINGREQ is billed. So sending PINGREQ too often (once every 30 seconds) will cause huge billing. I am planning to send PINGREQ less often - maybe 15 or 30 minutes once. I am curious if there are any downsides for sending PINGREQ less often.

Comment: The PINGREQ is sent by the client and indicates to the broker that the client is still alive, if anything happens  during this period  you  it will take you more time to notice that the client isn't alive. If your clients does not send any other type of packets is recommended to send the PINGREQ frequently.

Comment: The main downside is it may take longer to detect a [half open connection](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-10-alive-client-take-over/) leading to the potential for delays/message loss (if using QOS1 then messages should be retried upon reconnect). There may be ways to work around this but would need more info on your use-case (QOS, how often you send/receive etc). You also need to be aware of the the idle time limit; [20 mins for IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#idle_time_limit).

Comment: @Brits Main use case is to control appliances like light or fans. Messages to devices are sent rarely, but appliances should respond faster.

Comment: @PavanKumar I assume that the devices are not regularly sending out messages (just waiting for commands). In that case the risk of reducing the PING frequency is the delayed delivery of messages if/when the connection goes down in a way that the client does not detect (i.e. half open connection). The likelihood of this occurring in the first place depends upon the network connections involved. Perhaps consider making the PING frequency dynamic (increase it for connections where no timeouts have been detected and reduce again as soon as a timeout is detected).

Comment: @Brits let's say appliances is connected to mobile network (e.g 3g) and appliances is fitted in vehicle. I think in this case frequent pingreq is desirable, right?

Comment: @PavanKumar I'd agree with that in principal. However there are many factors involved and PINGs are not free (GCP charges, AWS does not but you would still pay for the traffic).

Comment: @Brits Oops! I thought AWS pingreq are free!!

Comment: @PavanKumar AWS does not charge but depending on your 3g plan you will still be paying for usage (PINGREQ/RESP packets are very small but if you send a lot of them it still adds up).